# turn the one-dimensional convolution and attention mechanism into a parallel module, instead of doing it sequentially

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I am using one-dimensional convolution and attention mechanism to extract time-series data features. At the beginning, I used one-dimensional convolution and attention mechanism to build the model sequentially. I tried to make convolution and attention mechanism parallel. Please help me to modify it. The code, the following is my original model construction, thank you very much

#model build

```
cnn_in=Input(shape=(look_backs,num_feature))
cnn_temp=Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,), activation='relu',strides=1,padding='same',input_shape=(look_backs,1))(cnn_in)
cnn_a=Attention(64)(cnn_temp)
lstm_temp=LSTM(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(cnn_temp)
lstm_temp=Bidirectional(LSTM(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))(cnn_temp)
out=Attention(64)(lstm_temp)
out=Dense(32,activation='relu')(out)
out=Dense(16,activation='relu')(out)
out=Dense(1)(out)

import os
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Lambda, Dot, Activation, Concatenate, Layer

debug_flag = int(os.environ.get('KERAS_ATTENTION_DEBUG', 0))
class Attention(object if debug_flag else Layer):

    def __init__(self, units=128, **kwargs):
        super(Attention, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units

    # noinspection PyAttributeOutsideInit
    def build(self, input_shape):
        input_dim = int(input_shape[-1])
        with K.name_scope(self.name if not debug_flag else 'attention'):
            self.attention_score_vec = Dense(input_dim, use_bias=False, name='attention_score_vec')
            self.h_t = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, -1, :], output_shape=(input_dim,), name='last_hidden_state')
            self.attention_score = Dot(axes=[1, 2], name='attention_score')
            self.attention_weight = Activation('softmax', name='attention_weight')
            self.context_vector = Dot(axes=[1, 1], name='context_vector')
            self.attention_output = Concatenate(name='attention_output')
            self.attention_vector = Dense(self.units, use_bias=False, activation='tanh', name='attention_vector')
        if not debug_flag:
            # debug: the call to build() is done in call().
            super(Attention, self).build(input_shape)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0], self.units

    def __call__(self, inputs, training=None, **kwargs):
        if debug_flag:
            return self.call(inputs, training, **kwargs)
        else:
            return super(Attention, self).__call__(inputs, training, **kwargs)

    # noinspection PyUnusedLocal
    def call(self, inputs, training=None, **kwargs):

        if debug_flag:
            self.build(inputs.shape)
        score_first_part = self.attention_score_vec(inputs)
        h_t = self.h_t(inputs)
        score = self.attention_score([h_t, score_first_part])
        attention_weights = self.attention_weight(score)
        context_vector = self.context_vector([inputs, attention_weights])
        pre_activation = self.attention_output([context_vector, h_t])
        attention_vector = self.attention_vector(pre_activation)
        return attention_vector

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(Attention, self).get_config()
        config.update({'units': self.units})
        return config
```